# Visual Studio Code - can we compare Metadata in two orgs

Tags: metadata, change-set, visualstudiocode, version-control

A client is moving away from change sets to Azure  Devs Ops. However, for now deployments are done using change sets,

The org size is small, and currently no custom code, only config - custom fields, page layouts, flexipages, recrord types, validation rules etc..

**Using VS Code, can we compare metadata from different sandboxes ?**
They have 3 sandboxes which could get a little bit out of sync. Thus, a quick comparison of metadata could help take the mystery out of where the differences have cropped up.

eg compare the diffrences in Pagelayouts in Dev Sandbox and QA sandbox.

Comment: vendor tools like Gearset, Copado, etc are great at this

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by cropredy, Unfortunately we don't have internal tools to compare metadata on different orgs.  However you can explore below free tools to compare metadata.

- [Salesforce Org Compare](https://sforgcompare.herokuapp.com/),
- [Metadata Glimpser](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B5HSYEA3&tab=e),
- [VS SalesforceDiff](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=chuckjonas.salesforce-diff&ssr=false#overview)